# Yii2 with composer and fxp/composer-asset-plugin

Tags: yii2, composer-php

I'm working on a project using Yii2 PHP framework. Yii2 uses ***composer*** with **fxp/composer-asset-plugin** to handle project dependencies.

The problem is when a new developer comes to the project and runs

```
git clone <project-repo>
composer install
```

or another developer wants to install a new extension with `composer require <package-name>` often (very often) something goes wrong and **composer** (or maybe **asset plugin**, I mentioned above) shows another unclear error message (maybe only for me). And the developer spends lots of time to find what that error meant and how to deal with it.

Today I've cloned project on Windows machine, installed the latest **composer** and **asset plugin** versions, run `composer install` and, after about 20 minutes waiting, got this:

[image]

On my Linux system same dependencies have been installed without errors.

**Question №1**
What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

**Question №2**
Is it so bad idea to add `vendor/` directory to version control? (I've read https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md)

**Question №3**
Maybe I'm doing something wrong or there is a secret, I'm not aware about, that allows to manage dependencies in Yii2 without such huge time loss.

Many thanks.

`composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
    "description": "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "basic", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url":  "https://github.com/ZeroVision/swiftmailer.git"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php": "~7.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "2.0.7",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "dev-fixStreamBufferTransport",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": ">=2.0.3",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-authclient": "^2.0@dev",
        "2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget": "~1.0",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-timepicker": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-rating": "*",
        "2amigos/yii2-gallery-widget": "~1.0",
        "2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget": "~1.0",
        "uran1980/yii2-scroll-to-top": "dev-master",
        "yii-cms/yii2-robokassa": "^1.1",
        "onokumus/metismenu": "v2.4.2",
        "rmrevin/yii2-fontawesome": "*",
        "dektrium/yii2-user": "*",
        "p2made/yii2-sb-admin-theme": "1.1.2",
        "p2made/yii2-p2y2-things": "*",
        "p2made/yii2-asset-collection": "*",
        "demi/image": "~1.0",
        "demi/cropper": "~1.0",
        "cyneek/yii2-widget-upload-crop": "dev-master",
        "Nemmo/yii2-attachments": "*",
        "2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget": "*",
        "rkit/yii2-ajaxform-plugin": "^0.0.4",
        "nsept/yii2-birthday-picker": "*",
        "bryglen/yii2-apns-gcm": "1.0.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
            "setPermission": [
                {
                    "runtime": "0777",
                    "web/assets": "0777",
                    "yii": "0755"
                }
            ],
            "generateCookieValidationKey": [
                "config/web.php"
            ]
        },
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you paste here your composer.json?

Answer (score 20):

Try installing the dev-master of the asset-plugin

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:dev-master"
```

It solved a lot of problems on our end.

Comment: not work for me :-(
`
PHP 7.1.33 (cli) (built: Nov 22 2019 18:28:25) ( NTS )
Composer version 2.0.8 2020-12-03 17:20:38
`